# HTML5 canvas animation with Delphi

Tags: delphi, flash, html5-canvas, vcl, delphi-10.1-berlin

I need to replace a Flash animation in a Delphi application. So far I have used a `TShockwaveFlash` component to load an SWF file. Used Adobe Animate to convert this SWF file into an HTML 5 canvas and changed some syntax for the action script.

The output from Adobe Animate is the following:

```
.html
.js
images/.png
```

How do I integrate these into my Delphi application to replace the old Flash animation? Not very experienced in web development.

Comment: i am using delphi version 10.1 and vcl

Comment: You need to embed a browser, for example with a `TWebBrowser` component.

Comment: You need to embed a web browser supporting HTML5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We installed [WebView2](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/) and used the TEdgeBrowser component.

You can access the script part in delphi in this way:

var Script: string := componentname+'.Enable.gotoAndStop(0);';
EdgeBrowser1.ExecuteScript(Script);